# Nested tables in markdown?

Tags: markdown

I need to create a nested-like table in markdown like this:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: You can always use raw HTML. If however, you are looking for a Markdown syntax, there is no standard. then we need to know which implementation you are using as there are many non-standard table implementations.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by nested? Images are not particularly helpful here. Input you have tried and/or the HTML output you expect would be much more helpful.

Comment: @Waylan, "Version V2" and "Return Value ..." span several cells. Therefore the rendered image can be seen as an outer 2x2 table with an inner 5x2 table insi in the cell (2,2) of the outer table.

Answer (score 18):

@Waylan is right, you can paste HTML (of a table generated with Markdown for example) inside a cell of Markdown table.

This requires some work because you need to examine the generated HTML of a rendered (fortunately browsers like Firefox let you examine the source of a rendered HTML).

The other drawback is that the result can be unreadable, for example:

```
|                |ASCII                          |HTML                         |
|----------------|-------------------------------|-----------------------------|
|Single backticks|`'Isn't this fun?'`            |'Isn't this fun?'            |
|Quotes          |`"Isn't this fun?"`            |<table>  <thead>  <tr>  <th></th>  <th>ASCII</th>  <th>HTML</th>  </tr>  </thead>  <tbody>  <tr>  <td>Single backticks</td>  <td><code>'Isn't this fun?'</code></td>  <td>‘Isn’t this fun?’</td>  </tr>  <tr>  <td>Quotes</td>  <td><code>"Isn't this fun?"</code></td>  <td>“Isn’t this fun?”</td>  </tr>  <tr>  <td>Dashes</td>  <td><code>-- is en-dash, --- is em-dash</code></td>  <td>– is en-dash, — is em-dash</td>  </tr>  </tbody>  </table>      |
|Dashes          |`-- is en-dash, --- is em-dash`|-- is en-dash, --- is em-dash|
```

renders to:

[image]

in the https://stackedit.io Editor.

Finally, your example would be something like:

```
|   |  Returned Value |
|--| -----------------|
| Version V2 |     <table>  <thead>  <tr>  Z-value</th>  <th>06</th>  </tr>  </thead>  <tbody>  <tr>  <td>Protocol</td>  <td>04 05</td>  </tr>  <tr>  <td>Protocol Sub</td>  <td>02</td>  </tr>  <tr>  <td>Application</td>  <td>11</td>  </tr>  <tr>  <td>Application Sub</td>  <td>00</td>  </tr>  </tbody>  </table>              |
```

and render into:

[image]

It is probably not worth it. Markdown is not for that (use LaTeX instead, or LaTeX embedded Markdown if you can)